# Streaming on low level DSL

Tags: internet, stream

I got DSL 2000 (280k/bits down, 19 up to 40 k/bits up), now I want to stream me for example coding live, so at a low FPS rate.
Would this be possible, and which tool / provider should I use for such low FPS rated streaming?
(feel free to post Windows Tools, if there are no matching available for Linux)

regards,

Comment: Sorry you're trying to make a stream of you on your computer? Screenshots or video from a webcam?

Comment: trying to stream of my own computer like "livestream.com"

Comment: And you need audio at the same time?

Comment: audio should be streamed to, because I want to stream music or comment on what I am doing

Answer (score 1):

why not give vlc streaming a try ? use lower bit rates and you should be good to go

Comment: +1 for VLC, and the documentation is awesome: http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/